# XAML - Personalize button behavior

Tags: c#, xaml, button, state

I'd like to personalize my button's behavior on some states, like `PointerOver` or `Disabled`. I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617071/make-the-button-transparent-on-mouse-over), wich gave me a big help, but I still don't get how to personalize the button with my personal resources. i.e. I'd like to change the button's background when it's disabled, so I wrote something like:

```
<Image x:Key="myImage" src="Images/myImage.png" />

[...]

<VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource myImage}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

But exception occurs. I can't tell you what's the exception, I think 'cause XAML is debugged by low-level c++ debugger and no particular exception is thrown.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
The exception is raised in the file App.g.i.cs at the foruth line of this block:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

EDIT2:
If I examine e in the debug session:

- [System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException] = {"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."}
- Message = "Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation.ObjectKeyFrame.Value'. [Line: 32
  Position: 91]"
- _stackTrace = null

Comment: You need to find out what the exception is. Then come back here when you know what it is.

Comment: I agree with PhoenixReborn. From the UnhandledException, you can look at "e" in the debugger and find out what the exception is and "e.Stacktrace" will show you where the exception was thrown. You can also enable "break on all exceptions" by going to VS menu "Debug|Exceptions..." and checking the item "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". This will stop the debugger where the exception originates.